# Doctrine override relation by field value

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Take a look at the following model:

```
class Team

    /**
     * @id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id_manager", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $manager;

    /** 
     * @id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Stadium")
     * @JoinColumn(name="stadium", referencedColumnName="stadium")
     */
    protected $stadium;
```

When I query for a team using array hidration I do:

```
$qb->select(['a', 'b', 'c']);
$qb->from(Team::class, 'a');
$qb->leftJoin('a.manager', 'b');
$qb->leftJoin('a.stadium', 'c');

$teams = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

For each team the structure is this:

```
[
    "id_manager": 3,
    "manager": [
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Billy"
    ],
    "stadium": 8
]
```

See how "manager" is loaded as an array (as expected), but "stadium". At the first sign looks like if the relation field has the same name as the column it keep the column value. Is there a way to avoid this situation without renaming the field `$stadium` neither column?

PS:  `$qb->select(['a', 'b', 'c as stadium2']);` did not work.

**EDIT** I have noticed that if I delete the `@id` annotation I get the structure expected.

Answer (score 0):

So manager's id should be the primary key for team as well? So your primary key is a foreign key at the same time? Don't recommend that.

I propose a team's primary key which is independent and have a relationship to the manager in a second attribute.

If you need the manager's id in your result you could achieve that e.g. in your custom respository or by an additional attribute and its getter in your Team class which is not mapped to ORM.

Comment: I totally agree with `primary key is a foreign key at the same time is not recommended`. But I am working under a consolidated database where the primary keys was assigned in that way

Comment: But you can solve it by establishing a OneToOne relationship between Team and Manager. To be honest I don't how this setup worked in the way you're describing it. only thing i can imagine is that the original team had no primary key at all.

Comment: The problem is that in in some way the id relation can not be loaded as a relation but as a field.

Comment: we should chat, but cannot currently